# How to change style of Mui Chip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use a `Mui` chip inside of a data grid. I have attempted to style it but I am unable to change the behaviour of the underlying `MuiIconButton` container that holds it.

So to test, I have tried

```
<Chip
     label="Info"
     sx={{
         '&.MuiChip-root': {
             height: 20,
             fontSize: '10px',
             color: 'red',
             borderRadius:0,
             '&:hover': {
                 color: 'blue',
                 height:20,
                 borderRadius:0,
                 backgroundColor: "green",
                },
            },
        }}
/>
```

This works fine on the actual chip itself, but on hover and click, the button still has the big oval background shape that pops up.

I have tired adding styling for both `&.MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root` and `MuiIconButton-root` within the chip element and also within the `DataGrid` element but I am not sure that I am doing it correctly as it has no effct on the button.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share an example in codesandbox, So We can look into the code and help you out.